# one-liner to delete a part of a column with matching pattern (sed/awk etc)

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, cut, paste

A very generic question but I am looking for the simplest way solve this very quickly and efficiently
I have  a file  with a very large number of lines which looks like this

```
  451267 sample1.txt  
  157444 sample2.txt  
  134864 sample2.txt
```

and I want result where the file(same or new) looks like

```
  451267 sample1   
  157444 sample2  
  134864 sample2
```

Comment: Simple and fast with cut `cut -d. -f1 filename`. Of if you prefer `awk -F. '{print $1}' filename`  If you want to know more about string manipulation see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with sed I believe.

`sed 's/.txt//g' file`

This command replaces the pattern '.txt' with nothing.

Comment: *uuoc*, better: `sed 's/.txt//g' file`